# HTML email for – why do some elements not display when mail is opened with Outlook 2010?

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook-2010

EDIT: added images.

I am developing a html email template. After considerable amounts of blood, sweat and tears, it now looks more or less the same in the mail clients we design for:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTu9l.png

But for some reason, Outlook 2010 won't display the subheading and main image.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EudEJ.png

All images are stored on the same server, but only the logo and the M icon display.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><title>Newsletter</title>

  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#f5f5f5; color:#695e4a; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin-top:0px; padding:auto;">

  <style type="text/css">

  a, h1, h2, span, p {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }



    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td{
      margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 /* border: 0;
*/  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
    }
    .readmore{
      color:#246877;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-decoration: none;
    } 


  </style>
    <table style="padding:none; border:none; border-spacing:0; width:608px" align="center" cellspacing="0">


  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9; width:3px; "></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" style="background-color:#ffffff; font-family: Arial, " HelveticaNeue?,Helvetica,sans-serif;?="">
      <br><a style="margin:50px 25px; font-size:9px; color:#b9b9b9; text-decoration:none" href="">View in browser</a>
      <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f6f6f6; margin:5px 25px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9; width:3px;  "></td>
  </tr>
   <!-- Header with LOGO, date, category, BEFORE content -->
  <tr>

    <td style="width:275px; height: 89px; background-color:#ffffff; padding:10px 0px 10px 25px"><img src="[removed due to non disclosure contract]"></td>
    <td style="text-align:right; width:275px; height: 89px; background-color:#ffffff; color:#6a604c; font-size:9px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:13px; padding-right:25px;">
      <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Monday, July 1st, 2013<br>optional communication category</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Heading Ribbon -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="background-color:#dbd1cd; height:50px;  padding-left:29px">
      <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="width:522px">
            <h1 style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:22px; font-weight: normal; color:#6a604c; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top: 17px;
line-height: 0px;">Minor change in membership Rules</h1>
          </td>
           <!-- Optional icon (mandatory, urgent etc) goes in this td -->
          <td style="padding-right:25px; padding-left:25px; width:28px"><img src="[removed due to non disclosure contract]" align="right"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- shadow below ribbon -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="height:4px;">
<img src="[removed due to non disclosure contract]">
</td>

  </tr>
  <!-- Features,  contained in a nested table -->
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9; width:3px; "></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;">
      <table style="padding:none; border:none; border-spacing:0;">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px 25px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <h2>Font-family is specified in global styles for each element</h2>
            <img src="[removed due to non disclosure contract]">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque molestie augue ut rutrum interdum. Curabitur varius nisl nec velit dictum feugiat. Nam et augue posuere elit sodales mattis ut nec justo. Etiam auctor rutrum leo in vulputate. Ut eget sem malesuada, consequat ligula id, rutrum lacus. Aenean tempor, magna tincidunt lobortis rutrum, urna arcu mollis diam, nec fermentum arcu mi sed lectus.
          </p>
            <a class="readmore" href="">Read more</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 10px 25px">
            subtitle, image, excerpt, <a>read more</a>
          </td>
          <td style="padding: 10px 25px">
            subtitle, image, excerpt, <a>read more</a>
          </td>
        </tr>


      </table>


    </td>
    <td style="border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9; width:3px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- optional features -->
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

My img tag was like this

```
<img src="http://mydomain/images/myimage.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="my image"   />
```

It worked fine in all other email clients but for Outlook I needed to include the www to make it show up:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain/images/myimage.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="my image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm i think that will display the images as well :) just put the `<img src="">` its complete path ....

Comment: EDIT - added images.
It displays correctly in Mail (osx), gmail, outlook 2007. Not in Outlook 2010.

Comment: i think its not the code in your problem its the outlook 2010 does not support images, i think:)

Answer (score 0):

They are so many rules for an html email.

for an image you should always put width, height and alt element

for exemple:

```
<img src="http://mydomaine/images/myimage.jpg" width="600" height="300" alt="my image" border="0" style="display:block" />
```

"display:block" is a hack for hotmail to display the good size of the image.

(btw are you sure that it's the good html code you gave? cause I can't see the line 83 in your screenshot: "Font-family is specified in global styles for each element" )